# LibGDX: Shader files in assets - Access is Denied

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shaders, glsl

I stored the glsl files in `android -> assets -> shaders` directory, but when I run the app, an error is displayed:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDebugAssets'.
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...android\assets\shaders (Access is denied)
```

But the problem goes away if I put those files in assets root folder. Can I not store shader files in asset subdirectories? Using Gdx v1.9.3.

EDIT: The issue is not there when running on Desktop, but only on Android. Didn't check others.

---

**UPDATE:** Apparently the issue got resolved today. I didn't make any changes but it's working now!

Comment: What code are you using? Using `Gdx.files.internal("shaders/<filename>.glsl")` works for me...

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm using too. But that error message I mentioned gets thrown.

Comment: Did you use the setup application to target Android initially? If not, you might have made a mistake (logical or otherwise) in the gradle setup. If that is not the problem the only other thing I know to tell you (without looking at the code that causes the exception) is to check for typos and make sure your Android project is configured correctly.

Comment: Yes I did that. I selected all target platforms during setup. I will check android gradle file again for any typos. This happens when running on Android, no problem in Desktop.

Comment: Apparently the issue got resolved today. I didn't make any changes but it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `Android Studio` or `IntelliJIdea` (don't know how `Eclipse` works).

These errors happen because of Windows administrative permissions. 
All you have to do is to open the parent folder (this one where your 'access denied' folder is in) in a windows file explorer. You need to rename the folder to anything you want and name it back with a previous name. If it was folder named `shaders`, rename it to `shaders2` and go back with `shaders`. `IntelliJ`/`Android Studio` will refresh the project itself and it will work.

This is caused by adding files directly to the project, but not to the folder itself ;) Happens to me on `Windows10` when running `Android Emulator` or a normal mobile phone plugged in.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why it got solved automatically the next time I opened the project.